# Android How to create ListView contain multiple different types object

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have 9 elements:

```
- person 1, person 2, person 3,
- animal 1, animal 2, animal 3,
- transport 1, transport 2, transport 3
```

of three different types:

```
- Person (photo, name, age, job, move),
- Animal (photo, name, age, feed, move), 
- Transport(photo, name, release date, fuel, move)
```

I want to create a `listview` of them using `ArrayAdapter`, suppose `Person` has no icon, `Animal` has like icon, `Transport` has star icon. like this [Image](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0By8vgjIxRDg_V1dKOUVYZS1udzg), but I don't understand how.

Many thanks for all support.

Comment: User `RecyclerView` with `getItemType`

Comment: see thi link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: create a custom adapter create an arraylist and a class for getter and setter method for  the arrylist to add item i think this is one way to achive this

Answer (score 0):

You should override methods from [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

```
getViewTypeCount()
```

and

```
getItemViewType(int position)
```

Same methods exists for [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html).